# Data structure that can efficiently store and check if the total of any three successively added elements is equal to given total

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Example:

- Empty container with no existing totals.
- Add {1, 2, 3} which means that there is only one existing total (1 + 2 + 3 = 6).
- Now add {4} element which creates additional total from {2, 3, 4}. There would be now two totals (1 + 2 + 3 = 6 and 2 + 3 + 4 = 9).

Comment: `int[3]` and an `int` index value could do it, using the array as a circular buffer. If you don't want to manage the circular nature yourself, a [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) can be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of a list (to keep track of the elements you added) and a map from the sum to the elements:

```
public class SummingList {
    // Store the elements added in order
    private List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();

    // Map form the sum to the index(es) that sum up to that number
    private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> sumIndexes;

    /** Expose elements from the list: */
    public int get(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }

    /** Add an element to the data structure */
    public add(int element) {
        list.add(element);

        // If there are now at least three elements in the data structure,
        // sum them:
        int size = list.size();
        if (size >= 3) {
             int sum = list.get(size - 3) + list.get(size - 2) + list.get(size - 1);
             sumIndexes.computeIfAbsent(sum, k -> new LinkedList<>()).add(size - 3);
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Returns a list of indexes in the list, where each index is the beginning
     * of a series of three elements who's sum is the passed {@code sum}.
     * If no such indexes exist, an empty list is returned.
     */
    public List<Integer> getSequencesWIthSum(int sum) {
        return Collections.unmodifiable(
            sumIndexes.getOrDefault(sum, Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. The API in this example is admittedly kind of weird, but it shows the basis of the idea. It can easily be tweaked to return something more suitable to your needs.
2. If you need to generalize the implementation to hold sums of larger series, not just triplets, it may be a good idea to cache a "rolling window" sum. I haven't done so in order to keep the code more concise.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solve {
static int index = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);
    arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
    findSum(arrayList);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    moreInput(s, arrayList);
}

private static void process(ArrayList<Integer> deque, Scanner s) {
    Integer input = s.nextInt();
    if (input == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number to be added");
        Integer value = s.nextInt();
        insert(deque, value);
        moreInput(s, deque);
    } else if (input == 0) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private static void moreInput(Scanner s, ArrayList<Integer> deque) {
    System.out.println("Want to add new number ?" + "Press 1 to add, 0 to 
stop");
    process(deque, s);
}

static void insert(ArrayList<Integer> deque, Integer value) {
    if (!(index < deque.size())) {
        index = 0;
    }
    deque.remove(index);
    deque.add(index, value);
    findSum(deque);
    index++;

}

static void findSum(ArrayList<Integer> deque) {
    Integer res = 0;
    Iterator itr = deque.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Integer num = (Integer) itr.next();
        System.out.print(num + " ");
        res += num;
    }
    System.out.print(": " + res + "\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Used an ArrayList to solve.